# sqlalchemy session execute messes up valid postgres syntax

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, syntax-error

I have an application that needs to interact with a database through use of good old fashioned models as well as generated sql.

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
cmd = """insert into "STO_BANK_CONTROL" ("isn","TRANS_REF_NO","weird") values (8078638,'#:0057/13           ','');"""
Session.execute(cmd);
```

This raises the exception:

```
StatementError: A value is required for bind parameter u'0057' (original cause: InvalidRequestError: A value is required for bind parameter u'0057') u'insert into "STO_BANK_CONTROL" ("isn","TRANS_REF_NO","weird") values (8078638,\'#%(0057)s/13           \',\'\');' [{}]
```

but if I copy `cmd` straight into the psql console it works just fine.

My question is:

Why is sqlalchemy breaking working code and how do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the colon. That notation is used to specify bind parameters. To fix it:

```
cmd = cmd.replace(':','\\:')
```